# Finding max changestamp

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I am using gdata-python-client. Is there a way to get max changestamp?

I built complete directory structure using gdata.docs.DocsClient.GetAllResources(). To poll for new changes, I would like to get the max changestamp.

Only way I could think right now is iteratively requesting multiple DocsClient.GetChanges(changestamp=i+100, max_results=100) - which is costly if I have thousands of changes.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call GetMetadata to retrieve information about the user and check the value of the docs:largestChangestamp element:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#getting_general_information_about_a_users_account

Comment: Remember to approve the answer if that is what you needed

Comment: Sorry. S.O. noob here. How do I approve?

Comment: Claudio, is there an equivalent way to do this using the Drive API?

Comment: You need to retrieve the About resource (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about#resource) from the About feed: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get